# Need help with re for matching and getting the value python

Tags: python

Need help regarding re.

```
file =  'file No.WR79050107006 from files'
```

So what I am trying to do is validate if file string contains WR + 11 digit.

```
result = re.match('^(\S| )*(?P<sr>(\d){11})(\S| )*', file)
```

Its validate only 11 digit but not WR before it.
How can I do that?

Using re after matching how can I get the match value ( WR79050107006)

I can do string find

```
index = file.find('file No.')
```

and then get the value of next 13 char.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If by "validate if file string contains WR + 11 digit" you mean "exactly 11, not 12+",

```
mo = re.search(r'WR(\d{11})(\D|$)', thestring)
```

should do.  If you actually mean "11 or more", there's no need for the `(\D|$)` part (or equivalent negative lookahead, etc).

**Edit**: as the OP now says in a comment that there might be whitespace between the WR and the digits, this can change to

```
mo = re.search(r'WR\s*(\d{11})(\D|$)', thestring)
```

the difference, of course, is in the `\s*` which means "0 or more whitespace characters here".

`mo` is `None` if `thestring` has no such match; otherwise, `mo.group(1)` gives you the 11-digits substring of interest.

Comment: hey thanks for replying 
mo = re.search(r'WR(\d{11})(\D|$)', thestring)
its working file but when I add mo = re.search(r'WR({})(\d{11})(\D|$)', thestring)
doing this when my string is 'no.WR 12345678910' basically for empty space after WR.
but above code does not work. any help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
result = re.search("No.WR\d{11}", file)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> file =  'file No.WR79050107006 from files'
>>> for item in file.split():
...     if "No.WR" in item:
...         d=item.replace("No.WR","")
...         if d.isdigit() and len(d) == 11:
...            print "ok"
...
ok
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. 
I was doing the same thing but using re its much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your comment on Alex's answer. Is the record valid if there is a space between the `WR` and the 11 digits?

Hopefully one of these examples help. Otherwise add the other variations and expected results to your question, and you should get answers that are straight to the point.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'(WR\d{11})(?:\D|$)', 'file No.WR79050107006 from files')
['WR79050107006']
>>> re.findall(r'(WR)(\d{11})(?:\D|$)', 'file No.WR79050107006 from files')
[('WR', '79050107006')]
```

Whitespace between the WR and the 11 digits

```
>>> re.findall(r'(WR)(\d{11})(?:\D|$)', 'file No.WR 79050107006 from files')
[]
>>> re.findall(r'(WR)\s*(\d{11})(?:\D|$)', 'file No.WR 79050107006 from files')
[('WR', '79050107006')]
>>>
```

Anything between WR and the 11 digits

```
>>> re.findall(r'(WR).*(\d{11})(?:\D|$)', 'file No.WR!@#$%79050107006 from files')
[('WR', '79050107006')]
```